# Reading a number from a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file which contains only one large number. I need to save this number in an integer variable in order to use it in mathematical operations.

I've tried: `var=$(<filename)` but it saves it as string.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. One thing you can do is `declare -i var=$(<file)` (assuming bash), but that does not gain you a whole lot.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work.. I need to check if the number is prime and some other operations so I need to have it as integer so i can do "$var+2" as a simplest case

Comment: And what have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you got the notion there is an integer variable in shells (bash e.g.)?

Comment: @Rayya bash has no **'typed'** variables, only ways to tell the interpreter how you wish to use it. If you have a number in `filename`, you get it in `var`. You can confirm with `printf " int: '%d'  string: '%s'  var-1 : '%d'\n" "$var" "$var" $((var - 1))`

Answer (score 11):

There are no integer variables in common shellscript (bash, sh) -- all variables are either strings or arrays. So just use the variable normally:

```
$ echo 2 > test
$ X=$(< test)
$ Y=$(($X + 2))
$ echo $Y
4
```

Comment: I need to use it inside a new var not inside "echo".. when I use inside this code to check if it's prime or not it stops at "expr" because it's a string even if I wrote it as $(($var/2)) for example


i=2
f=0
while [ $i -le `expr $num / 2` ]
do
if [ `expr $num % $i` -eq 0 ]
then
f=1
fi
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
if [ $f -eq 1 ]
then
echo "The number is composite"
else
echo "The number is Prime"
fi

Comment: echo or var does not matter. I just updated the example to show how to use it in a var. I cannot read your sample code as it lost all formatting, but your problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you are attempting to read the value from a file and check whether it is prime or not, your problem isn't the value in the file. The problem is your shell syntax. Following along from your questions and comments, it looks like you are trying to do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

num=$(<"$1")

i=2
f=0

while [ $i -le $(expr $num / 2) ]; do 
    if [ $(expr $num % $i) -eq 0 ]; then 
        f=1
    fi 
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done 

if [ $f -eq 1 ]; then 
    echo "The number is composite" 
else 
    echo "The number is Prime" 
fi
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ cat dat/pnumber.txt
31

$ sh prime.sh dat/pnumber.txt
The number is Prime

$cat dat/npnumber.txt
32

$ sh prime.sh dat/npnumber.txt
The number is composite
```

The problem was you failed to recognize that `expr` is a separate command and must be enclosed in either backticks or `$()` to return the value of the expression to a variable or use it in test constructs.

If you would rather use the older **backtick** command substitution syntax, then the following is equivalent to what is shown above:

```
while [ $i -le `expr $num / 2` ]; do 
    if [ `expr $num % $i` -eq 0 ]; then 
        f=1
    fi 
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```